# How to export AWS RDS snapshot to your own S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am using a [SQL Server Express](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/) [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) instance. The RDS is backing up daily.

I've found that the RDS snapshot is actually stored in S3. But is it possible to export data to your own [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) bucket?

Comment: What is the reason you want to export them to your own S3 bucket? is it so you can use it with redshift or another tool? or is it for cost savings?

Answer (score 4):

Snapshots are stored in S3 but AWS do not make them visible.  Similar question/answer in AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=560995.  You will need to do a database dump.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx looks like a good guide on how to do this.

Update 3rd Feb:
AWS now allows you to access the s3 snapshot, you can either download and use it elsewhere or use directly using athena or redshift

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html

Comment: you can automate a copy of the database but not the actual snapshot.  The easiest thing could be to schedule a script to connect to the database and dump the database to a file instead of worrying about snapshots.  If you have to copy from the snapshot then you would have to bring up a new RDS database using the snapshot, connect to the database and then dump it to file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this using snapshots. You would have to export the data using something like mysqldump or the equivalent for your database.

Comment: You can only copy a snapshot to another snapshot within AWS. You can't copy it to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks.. one last question does the copied snapshot stay forever or same as the retention policy of the rds instance?

Comment: A copied snapshot counts as one of your manual snapshots. You can have up to 50 manual snapshots in a region at any one time. They stay around forever, or until you manually delete them.

Comment: Another reason this is annoying is that users ought to be able save $$$ by using s3-IA (it's around a third of the cost of s3 and snapshots are a perfect use case for IA).

Comment: @AndyHayden You should file a ticket with AWS support regarding that. Complaining about it here isn't going get it onto Amazon's radar.

Answer (score 1):

**For Googlers:**

As of 11/09/2020, **there is no way to access RDS snapshots directly**, nor to export them to S3.

The catch: **you may [export snapshot *_data_* to S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/announcing-amazon-relational-database-service-snapshot-export-to-s3/)**, but **NOT** the snapshot itself.

The **snapshot *_data_*** is provided in Parquet format thus is there for you to do analysis with Athena, etc. only.

For DR purposes, you may **copy snapshots** to a second region, or **share snapshots** to other accounts.

THE ABOVE IS FREQUENTLY SEEN IN CERTIFICATION EXAM.

Although for very-long backups, you may use the export-to-s3 features as [officially recommended](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html).

Answer (score 0):

RDS now provides the functionality to snapshot data into S3 bucket. Functionality provides full db backup or selective schema/table backups. Backups are stored into S3 bucket in Parquet Format.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/announcing-amazon-relational-database-service-snapshot-export-to-s3/

You can also automate it using lambda based on following sample --
https://github.com/aws-samples/rds-snapshot-export-to-s3-pipeline

**Update -- **
Currently, This functionality is not intended for data backup/restore purposes. Please see Jim's comment below.

Comment: I was looking into using the new feature to backup to S3. You can export Snapshots to S3 in some regions, you are not guaranteed to be able to restore them.

This from an Amazon employee
"Hello. This service is not built for DR purposes. We currently offload data to S3 for querying and analytics and you will not be able to load Parquet data back into RDS. Hope that answers you question. Feel free to PM me for more questions."

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/et3mxm/export_aurora_or_rds_snapshots_to_amazon_s3/

You can restore some aurora(mysql) or mysql s3 exports at this time.

Comment: This should be more visible inside of RDS. I would assume lots of people think when they export a snapshot to s3 that they can restore that snapshot from s3 into RDS if needed. This appears to not be the case.